# To get all the keys in JSONObject into String array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to create a json object from existing json object. For this i want to get all the keys in JSONObject to a String[] array. Is there any default method to get the keys into a String array. 
I found there exists a static method [here](http://json.org/javadoc/?org/json/JSONObject.html) getNames() but it's not working.

I can go over each key using iterator and can construct a keys String array but i want any default method if exists.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet so we could understand what's wrong with the `getNames()` methos?

Comment: getNames() doesn't exist at all i get a error telling the method doesn't exist

Comment: @kishore getNames() does exist, it depends on which library you are using. what are your imports?

Comment: org.json.JSONObject is the package i am using in my android application.

Answer (score 12):

To construct JSONObject from other JSONObject you can use constructor that accept JSONObject and array of keys names that should be copied. To do it:

```
Iterator keysToCopyIterator = firstJSONObject.keys();
List<String> keysList = new ArrayList<String>();
while(keysToCopyIterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) keysToCopyIterator.next();
    keysList.add(key);
}
String[] kesyArray = keysList.toArray(new String[keysList.size()]);
JSONObject secondJSONObject = new JSONObject(firstJSONObject, );
```

Answer (score 11):

There is not ***getNames()***, but there is ***Names()***